# Conditional formatting of bgcolor in html table

Tags: javascript, php, html

As a manufacturing company we measure and record data for the parts we make. Up to now these have been recorded on a spreadsheet, Drawing dimensions entered in one column and actual measured value in another, and thus the cell where actual measured value is entered changes background colour to show if within allowed dimension 
In excel this can be set up so happens dynamically. 
Can this be done on HTML table as and when information is entered.

Comment: Yes, assign colors to css classes. When generating the table check the value and assign the appropriate class. This is too broad for SO as is. If you have code you've tried please add that.

Comment: The question is too broad. You can't enter information into html tables. For this you need some JS solution, some "datagrid" library. And these libraries usually have some rendering customizations to achieve what you ask.

Comment: Agree vague as not sure what is the best way to do, is js, php, css the best way to achieve similar to what can be done using a spreadsheet and conditional formatting

Answer (score 0):

This is a vague question, but I can try giving you an answer. 
A decent solution might be to attach some Angular.js code to the HTML table so that it updates from an SQL database. Pulling code from the database where you'll update with the values you want to input, and it will automatically update the HTML table(this is because angular.js is mostly used edit DOM elements).

You'll be able to create/call javascript/jQuery functions as well that can evaluate whether or not the data is within the specified parameters, have it send the result to your angular function and change the attributes of the table so that the CSS can choose what colour the data row should be.